# Can't hide navigation controls in WPF Frame

Tags: c#, wpf

I've got this `Frame` here, and I've hidden the Nav UI in the XAML:

```xml
<Frame x:Name="ExamsTabFrame" Source="ExamsIndex.xaml" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden"/>
```

I've even set it in my C#:

```cs
    public partial class ExamsTab : Page {
        public ExamsTab() {
            InitializeComponent();
            ExamsTabFrame.NavigationUIVisibility = NavigationUIVisibility.Hidden;
        }
    }
```

I'm using a `Hyperlink` to navigate:

```xml
 <Hyperlink NavigateUri="SelectExamTemplate.xaml">New Exam</Hyperlink>
```

When I first launch the app, the first page has the controls hidden. When I click and navigate to the second page, they are shown again! And they remain if I go back and forth between pages.

I'll also note that if I put my cursor on the `Frame`, the properties window says that `NavigationUIVisibility` is set to `Visible`, which is strange.

What's going on?

Comment: Are you call `ExamsTabFrame = new Frame()` somewhere?

Comment: No, do I need to do that even when I'm indicating the frame in the xaml?

Comment: No, I just guessed if you've reset the settings with making new instance of `Frame` and assigning it to `ExamsTabFrame`. Your code is incomplete and hard for understaing the problem.